# "someVariable is None" always false w/ value derived from optparse result

Tags: python, sockets

I'm really getting mad 'cause of a problem I do not manage to get through while programming a simple and didactic portscanner in python. Here's the code:

```
def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage%prog "+\
    "-H <target host> -p <target port>")
    parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', \
    help='specify target host')
    parser.add_option('-p', dest='tgtPort', type='string', \
    help='specify target port[s] separated by comma')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    tgtHost = options.tgtHost
    tgtPorts = str((options.tgtPort)).replace(",", " ").split()
    if (tgtHost is None) | (tgtPorts is None):
        print '[-] You must specify a target host and port[s].'
        exit(0)
```

it all works as expected, apart from one thing: the (tgtPorts is None) check does not seem to work, while the tgtHost control works fine. In other words, this is what happens without a specified -H option:

```
    $ python portscanner.py -p 21
    [-] You must specify a target host and port[s].
```

while with the host and without -p here's what happens:

```
    $ python portscanner.py -H 1234

    [+] Scan Results for: 0.0.4.210
    Scanning port None
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "portscanner.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
    File "portscanner.py", line 43, in main
    portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)
    File "portscanner.py", line 29, in portScan
    connScan(tgtHost, int(tgtPort))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

So the script throws an error because it cannot convert None to int, and that's the point of the consistence check. I've already tried to change (tgtPorts is None) in (tgtPorts[0] is None), but nothing changed. Googled for it as well, but noone seems to have had the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Next time you ask something here, consider following the guidelines at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- as currently written, this question is unlikely to be helpful to others, since it's very specific to your code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm sorry, I'm new here and I wanted to give every information I could, but I noticed that most of the code I posted was totally useless in regards of my question. Edited the post, hope this is more portable :)

Comment: Much better indeed! I've tried to improve the title a bit as well -- using `[...]` suggests that your value might be a list or a list comprehension (both of which cases suggest a different actual cause and resolution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *string* with the word `'None'` in it, not the `None` object.

You made it a string here:

```
tgtPorts = str((options.tgtPort)).replace(",", " ").split()
```

Rather than use `str()` there, test for `options.tgtPort` having a true value (e.g. not `None` or an empty string):

```
if options.tgtPort:
    tgtPorts = options.tgtPort.replace(",", " ").split()
```

Note that `|` is **bitwise** OR, you should really use `or` instead. I'd test for the options first, *then* parse:

```
if not (options.tgtHost and options.tgtPort):
    print '[-] You must specify a target host and port[s].'
    exit(1)
```

Here both omitting the options and not specificing a value is an error.

Personally, I'd use the [`argparse` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) here and use required arguments, with the *ports* argument set to `nargs='+'` to capture one or more values. Error handling is then done by `argparse` as well.

Comment: Thanks, not only that worked, but you explained it in a clear and easily understandable way.